# Ignore * in css

Tags: css

In a project I have this style how can I make an element unaffected by this without modifying this rule?

```css
*, p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: You can't. You have to edit the rule, or add a subsequent and/or more specific rule.

Comment: Here's what you should do: 1. remove that ridiculous ruleset, 2. at the top of the styles add: `:root { font: 300 1.75ch/1.25 'Segoe UI' }`

Comment: Is it just one element you want to ignore this setting or all of them. Either way investigate font-size: initial to go back to the default setting.